# Model size, expressivity and overfitting - confusion about a statement in Goodfellow et al

Tags: neural-networks, bias-variance-tradeoff

In Goodfellow et al. book Deep Learning chapter 12.1.4 they write

> These large models learn some function f(x), but do so using many more parameters than are necessary for the task. Their size is necessary only due to the limited number of training examples.

I am not able to understand this. Large models are expressive but if you train them on few examples they should also overfit. So what do the authors mean by saying large models are necessary precisely because of limited number of training examples. This seems to go against the spirit of using more bias when training data is limited.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately above, he mentioned ensembles, so it's likely that he's referring to the common practice of training many models at once in an ensemble (which obviously inflates the number of parameters), which has been shown to improve performance on even limited amounts of data [see here](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Beluch_The_Power_of_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf).

> this seems to go against the spirit of using more bias when training
> data is limited.

I guess ensemble methods are one of those cases where the number of parameters is increased, but (depending on the exact ensembling method), the overall effect can be regularizing.

Alternatively, he could also be referring to "[double descent](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.02292)", a phenomenon in which increasing the number of parameters can increase test performance, counter to conventional understanding.

Comment: +1 But I wonder if double descent a plausible phenomenon that Goodfellow et al could be referring to in *Deep Learning*. This book was published in 2016, but the paper you cite was submitted to arXiv in 2019. Were double descent papers published prior to 2016?

Comment: beyond some relatively obscure papers.. not really, but i think the general idea that "bigger models are better" was at least "common folklore", even though it may not have been rigorously studied.

Comment: for example, the comment "We conjecture that in spite of the larger number of
parameters and the greater depth of our nets compared to (Krizhevsky et al., 2012), the nets required less epochs to converge due to (a) **implicit regularisation imposed by greater depth**" in the 2014 VGG paper (emphasis mine)

Comment: That's a good find! Thanks for running it down! I was poking through citations myself but didn't find anything to conclusively related to double descent before 2016. The "common folklore" explanation makes sense -- researchers will find something odd or unexpected before building a systematic research project to analyze and understand it.